# SQL: Get all hits for unique days (timestamps)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have a database table which contains id, action, timestamp for example. I want to get the unique days with corresponding hits/views.

Something like this:

```
    Date ------ Hits
 2018-01-10       5
 2018-01-11     542 
 2018-01-12      74
```

My approach was this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME (timecreated, '%d.%m.%y') AS 'date' 
FROM `mdl_logstore_standard_log` 
WHERE action = 'viewed'
```

That lists me all unique days but if I'll add `count(action) AS 'hits'` to the SELECT statement it will just show me the first day with the sum of all hits.

How can I solve this query? I'm grateful for any hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group results using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME (timecreated, '%d.%m.%y') AS `date`, COUNT(action) AS hits 
FROM `mdl_logstore_standard_log` 
WHERE action = 'viewed'
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME (timecreated, '%d.%m.%y')
ORDER BY `date`
```

Comment: That's nearly perfect. Thanks for that! Only problem the dates are ordered by the days, so the order is wrong. Like `01.01.2018, 02.01.2017, 03.01.2016, 10.01.2018`

Comment: Updated my answer. Use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Oh yeah, how could i forgot. Now its working perfectly. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For your requested output, you should really do:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`, COUNT(*) AS hits
FROM `mdl_logstore_standard_log` 
WHERE action = 'viewed'
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME (timecreated, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY MIN(timecreated);
```

The `order by` uses `MIN(timecreated)` so it will work even if you change the format.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely reconsider the query